# Is it possible for material-ui's timepicker component to display to picked time within the opened dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timepicker, material-table

I want to display the timepicker value as it changes on the [TimePicker](https://mui.com/components/time-picker/#basic-usage) component dialog. Is that possible ? It should basically look the same as the [StaticTimePicker](https://mui.com/components/time-picker/#static-mode) component, except when it comes to the displayed time.

In Summary : What I want is for the TimePicker component in the second picture to display the selected time, just like the StaticTimePicker in the first picture.

**1 - StaticTimePicker:**

[image]

**2 - TimePicker:**

[image]

Comment: So you essentially want to turn the time-picker component to a clock? I am sure there are libraries out there for that. If you truly need this, just keep updating time-picker default value over and over - which would essentially make point of picking the time useless I guess.

Comment: Sorry if It's hard to understand. What I want is for the `TimePicker` component in the second picture to display the selected time, just like the `StaticTimePicker` in the first picture.

Comment: I still don't get. Then just **use** the `StaticTimePicker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a prop to do this, `showToolbar={true}`. It can be found in [the API documentation](https://mui.com/api/time-picker/).

This is How it should be used :

```
<TimePicker
  showToolbar={true}
  label="Time"
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

Here is a [code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/localizedtimepicker-material-demo-forked-niwlud?file=/demo.js:1447-1476) for more context.

Answer (score -1):

Then just use the `StaticTimePicker` I don't understand your problem.

```js
export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(
    new Date(),
  );

  const handleChange = (newValue: Date | null) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
  <StaticTimePicker
    displayStaticWrapperAs="mobile"
    value={value}
    onChange={(newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fgwzeg?file=demo.tsx

Comment: The behavior of StaticTimePicker does not fit my needs. The question is whether it's possible to keep TimePicker and just add the displayed time on top of the clock. Like circled in red in the first picture.

Comment: To be more precise, I want to avoid having to create a custom dialog for it and a custom text field for it to behave like the TimePicker  component. Would be much easier to just add the extra time value on top of the time picker clock.